# How can I improve Yorick's damage without making him too squishy?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm testing Yorick as AD carry (sometimes is needed a top or mid that are not AP and does not need more tank), so I tested some builds but I didn't like so much about the damage received.

Here what I did in one test:

- Manamune
- Mercury's Treads
- Trinity Force
- infinite Edge
- Atma's Impaler
- and the last item i didn't finish, i was thinking in Warmogs or Spirit Visage.

The output was good (solo baron with an easy time, good damage, good resistence), but he was not resistant enough (This is why warmog or sv).

He attack speed is pretty low for Blood thrist instead of Infinite edge.

*I have build him as Tank the whole time, he damage is great, but can't say that he can be a carry with a tank's build.*

- **Which equip should I get for last item?**
- **Should I change IE For BT?**

NOTE: I think this question may help others champions like Nasus or Urgot.

I am really in a loss here, really appreciate some help

Comment: Honestly, you can't do much more damage than that build and expect to stay alive. Yorick is a bruiser more than an AD carry for a reason - he's a melee that can stay in the fight and keep others in the fight too with his ultimate. Melee characters tend to fail when not built tanky. Because they have to get in people's faces, they tend to take lots of damage. However, for your experiment, I think the synergy with IE and Atma's is better than bloodthirster, and Warmog's will boost your damage as well as make up for the lack of lifesteal (which has been nerfed recently anyways).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To answer your questions:**

- In your build I would take Warmog's Armor or Guardian Angel as the last item.
- I think Infinity Edge is better since it works well with Atma's Impaler

However, you cannot think like that. There is no build which is generally good. Sometimes it is better to get this item othertimes that item.

**If you want a general build for Yorick I would go for this one:**

- Boots of Speed + 3 or 4 health pots (4 pots - when solo top, wait near the fountain and buy 4th pot ASAP)
- Tear of the Goddess => Manamune
- probably Mercury Treads unless they have a heavy ad team, then I would go for Ninja Tabi
- straight for Atma's Impaler
- Warmog's Armor (tankier build) or Frozzen Mallet (better chasing)
- The other one of the previously mentioned items or the new item Maw of Malmortius
- Trinity Force (damage) / Guardian Angel (tanky build) / Infinity Edge (in case I have Frozen Mallet)

In case of a need I would upgrade boots before finishing Manamune, but after Tear of the Goddess. If I woudlnt be doing very well I would also get Wriggle's Lantern after Manamune or even before that and Spirit Visage, but those are items you want to sell in late game.

**Early** boots upgrade and Atma will give you enough resists and in combination with Manamune you will have circa **250 AD**.

Finally, I think that Yorick is better with a tankier build rather than AD.

**Ad NOTE:** I think Nasus benefits more from a far different build. Urgot is also good with Manamune and Atma, but before Atma he really needs Brutaliser and after Atma it is better to go different items. You can also build Frozen Heart before Atma which makes you even tankier and gives you some damage, too (since you have Manamune).

Comment: Sometimes eve Last Whisper can be handy when enemy team has plenty of Armor.

Comment: i tested warmog as the third item, works well, but not good damage. LW is a good call (I think) Thanks for your answer =) Good list of gear you made.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried my best although I am not completely a Yorick player :) I thnk Yorick is quite fat in the beginning so you can get Atma before Warmog, so Warmog would be 4th as I suggested. However, Warmog is more about sustain and therefore more damage in a longer fight. Obviously it is useless as a burst item (ad item).